# What's the two Gradle's mean in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Two version in `gradle-wrapper.properties`(distributionUrl gradle-2.4-all.zip) and build.gradle(`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'`)? they are two different version!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file you set the version of the **Gradle**. For example the 2.4 version.

With

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
```

inside your gradle files, you set the version of the **android plugin for Gradle.** They are different. You can find more info about the android plugin [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/plugin-for-gradle.html).

Comment: If we have the gradle plugin why we need gradle?

Comment: Gradle is the build system.The android plugin uses the gradle DSL to build the android code. You can't run the android plugin without gradle.